# Group By days interval (aging type)

Tags: mysql

I would lIke to have Mysql group by days interval for example group by every 20 days from current day, like 1 - 20, 21 - 40, 41 - 60 and son on up to lets 120 days. The user can choose the days interval and up to how many days

Comment: And your question is?  What do you have already?

Answer (score 2):

```
select floor(days / 20) as daygroup, count(*)
from mytable
group by daygroup
```